# How to recognize a field name without quotation marks with a regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, token, lexer

I write a parser to recognize strings of this type: `TERM : MATCH_TERM`

I had initially allowed to write the `TERM` part only between single or double quotes (`'TERM'` or `"TERM"`). I would now like to allow the `TERM` part to be written without quotes around it.

My regexes for recognizing the `TERM` part surrounded by quotes work well and are as follows:

```
const StringDoubleQuote = createToken({ name: "StringDoubleQuote", pattern: /"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"/ });
const StringSimpleQuote = createToken({ name: "StringSimpleQuote", pattern: /'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'/ });
```

For these regular expressions I didn't need to specify the `:` character as marking the end of the token because the quote mark already had that usage.

To make it possible to write the `TERM` part without quotation marks around it, I used the following regular expression:

```
const StringWithoutQuote = createToken({ name: "StringWithoutQuote", pattern: /[\w!@#\$%\^&.-]+/ });
```

To define the **lexer** part of the parser created with **chevrotain** I wrote the following code which defines the possible tokens:

```
const StringWithoutQuote = createToken({ name: "StringWithoutQuote", pattern: /[\w!@#\$%\^&.-]+/ });
const StringDoubleQuote = createToken({ name: "StringDoubleQuote", pattern: /"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"/ });
const StringSimpleQuote = createToken({ name: "StringSimpleQuote", pattern: /'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'/ });
const And = createToken({ name: "And", pattern: /(AND|and)/ });
const Or = createToken({ name: "Or", pattern: /(OR|or)/ });
const WhiteSpace = createToken({
    name: "WhiteSpace",
    pattern: /[ \t\n\r]+/,
    group: Lexer.SKIPPED
});
const Colon = createToken({ name: "Colon", pattern: /:/ });
const Star = createToken({ name: "Star", pattern: /\*/ });

//.... Many other token

const allTokens = [
    WhiteSpace,
    Colon,
    Star,
    And,
    Or,

    //At this level I also tried to put StringWithoutQuote after the string tokens with quotes in the allTokens array

    StringWithoutQuote,
    StringDoubleQuote,
    StringSimpleQuote
];
```

My problem now:
I'll take two example strings:

- **aggregateType:***
- **orderInfo.orderDate:***

For the first string (**aggregateType:***) whatever the syntax used (with or without quotes) the parser works well and returns the expected result.

But for the second string (**orderInfo.orderDate:***), the syntax with quotes (**'orderInfo.orderDate':*** or **"orderInfo.orderDate":***) allows the parser to work well and return me the expected result.

But with the syntax without quotes (**orderInfo.orderDate:***), the parser returns me the following error: `Error: Failing to parse of string <orderInfo.orderDate:*>`. I'm not sure, but I really feel like it's the addition of a dot `.` in the `TERM` part that's causing the error. However, in my regex (`/[\w!@#\$%\^&.-]+/`) I did put that the dot `.` is one of my special characters to be taken into account in the token.

Does anyone see what I did wrong that is causing this behavior?

Thanks in advance if you take the time to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the solution was to define a "longer possible pattern" that allows to say each time I check the presence of this keyword (in my case **and** or **or**) I also check if it is not a less specific identifier (in my case StringWithoutQuote).

The more detailed explanation is at the end of the constructor paragraph of this link [more detailed explanation in documentation](https://chevrotain.io/documentation/0_7_2/classes/lexer.html#constructor%22%5Dhttps://chevrotain.io/documentation/0_7_2/classes/lexer.html#constructor)

The definition of the lexer thus becomes:

```
const StringWithoutQuote = createToken({ name: "StringWithoutQuote", pattern: /[\w!@#\$%\^&.-]+/ });
const StringDoubleQuote = createToken({ name: "StringDoubleQuote", pattern: /"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"/ });
const StringSimpleQuote = createToken({ name: "StringSimpleQuote", pattern: /'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'/ });
const And = createToken({ name: "And", pattern: /(AND|and)/, longer_alt: StringWithoutQuote });  //here you need to add loger_alt property
const Or = createToken({ name: "Or", pattern: /(OR|or)/, longer_alt: StringWithoutQuote });  //here you need to add loger_alt property
const WhiteSpace = createToken({
    name: "WhiteSpace",
    pattern: /[ \t\n\r]+/,
    group: Lexer.SKIPPED
});
const Colon = createToken({ name: "Colon", pattern: /:/ });
const Star = createToken({ name: "Star", pattern: /\*/ });
 
const allTokens = [
    WhiteSpace,
    Colon,
    Star,
    And,
    Or,
    StringWithoutQuote,
    StringDoubleQuote,
    StringSimpleQuote
];
```